# How to do a wcf between service and windows form?

Tags: wcf

I have a service that update Database.I want show in another form in same Computer each change in gridview.Please help me with example

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: I am new in c#.I do not make a example